# Nodejs background running Cannot read property'query' of undefined problem

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax

I am a front-end learner. When I use the interface address provided by the background in a project, the nodejs background will report the error as shown in the figure. I would like to ask is it due to Mysql database password error or address error? But my database username and password are correct. Thank you for asking for an answer.

ajax operation
[image]

Wrong reporting
[image]
[db.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6kdT.png)

Comment: Where you defined the query?

Comment: You need to show your `models/db.js` code, that is where the exception happens.

Comment: @MadWard look this

Comment: @Vivek Sorry, I don't understand you. I don't understand you very well.